# Why are Android layout file names so limited?

Tags: android, file, names

It's good to have consistency in file names.

MyActivity.java contains the public class MyActivity

I would like the xml file with its layout to be called res/layout/MyActivity.xml

But I get an error message saying "Invalid file name: must contain only [a-z0-9_.]"

So two questions:

1. Why is the character set so limited (not even upper case?  Come on!)  - Ah - this restriction is probably in place so you will never be screwed by filesystems that don't make a distinction between upper and lower case, like Apple's HFS+ (although see Wikipedia for the gory story http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_systems#cite_note-note-35-77 )
2. Which filenames are restricted - all of res?  just res/layout?   res/layout plus some other folders?

Can anyone confirm 1, and give details on 2?

Thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why is the character set so limited

Because the name has to be a valid Java identifier, so you can use constants like `R.layout.foo` to identify the layout at runtime.

> Which filenames are restricted - all
>   of res? just res/layout? res/layout
>   plus some other folders?

Anything in `res/`

Comment: That part I can't explain, other than your OS filesystem theory.

Comment: Thanks for a plausible explanation, but I wonder if there is more.

Comment: Mark -- thank you so much -- I was just looking at your Busy Coder book today, and thinking "I have got to buy a copy of this" (and also groaning at the learning curve implied).  Cheers,

  Peter

Comment: thanks, this helped with some confusion around naming images placed in res like "bookmark.white.png" and "bookmark.red.png". not immediately obvious that file names shouldn't include any extra periods in them, but after seeing this it makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure of the reason for `#1`. Never seen an explanation in any readings about Resources. For `#2` from my experience anything that will be used as a id in java e.g., `R.drawable.marker`, `R.string.default_message` has to follow those rules of `[a-z0-9_]`.

Answer (score 0):

When using MacOS X as a development platform, almost any developer dealing with cross platform code will sooner or later run into the issue that source code from a Linux/UNIX project cannot be built after download/checkout/clone because the project has two identically named files in a single directory that only vary in case; and on OS X that means you end up with just one file as the second one will overwrite the first one.

Of course HFS+ can be case-sensitive, but this can only be configured when you format a partition and by default all Macs come with preinstalled OS X on a preformatted partition with a case-insensitive HFS+ (as that is the default mode for HFS+). So you would first have to reformat your newly bought Mac and reinstall OS X to achieve that goal. And then be prepared for trouble as many apps rely on case-insensitivity on the Mac; a very famous example is Steam (you cannot run Steam from a case-sensitive HFS+).

And it's not just MacOS. FAT is case-insensitive and while NTFS can be case-sensitive (just like HFS+), it isn't by default. Also I think SMB isn't as per protocol spec (at least older versions). The filesystem used on CDs isn't, and so on.

So I guess to avoid any troubles straight from the beginning, Google thought it's a good idea to force files to be all lower case, in which case it doesn't matter what filesystem you are using or how it is configured. Of course, that's a bit stupid if you can still run into that issue with your source code files, however that these may be mixed case is a decision that predates Android and that has been made by Sun many years before Google even dreamed of that system.